# Swift - Stream audio between device with Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: swift, streaming, audio-streaming, multipeer-connectivity

I have to resign after a long search on google and stackoverflow...

I develop my app on Swift.

I want to stream audio, playing on a smartphone (master), to another (slave).

There s a very good tutorial on objective C, but it's very complicated to find the same on Swift.

I follow this tutorial : http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/[1](http://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-multipeer-connectivity/)

The connectivity between each device is working. But now, i would like to code for streaming a song. You will find below what i have done. But when i m testing, there's no song playing from the master device. Weird no ?

```
   func sendColor(colorName : String) {
        NSLog("%@", "sendColor: \(colorName)")

    if session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        var error : NSError?
        do {
            try self.session.sendData(colorName.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, toPeers: session.connectedPeers, withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)

            //envoie son

            let sineURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("tiesto", withExtension: "mp3")!
            let asset = AVAsset(URL: sineURL)
            var assetReader:AVAssetReader


            do{
                assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: asset)
            }catch{
                fatalError("Unable to read Asset: \(error) : \(__FUNCTION__).")
            }

            let track = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio).first
            let outputSettings: [String:Int] =
            [ AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
                AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: 0,
                AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: 0,
                AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
                AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved: 0]

            let trackOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track!, outputSettings: outputSettings)

            assetReader.addOutput(trackOutput)
            assetReader.startReading()



            let sampleData = NSMutableData()

            while assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatus.Reading {
                  print("la aussi ")
                if let sampleBufferRef = trackOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() {
                    if let blockBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBufferRef) {
                        let bufferLength = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBufferRef)
                        let data = NSMutableData(length: bufferLength)
                        CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBufferRef, 0, bufferLength, data!.mutableBytes)
                        let samples = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>(data!.mutableBytes)
                        sampleData.appendBytes(samples, length: bufferLength)
                        CMSampleBufferInvalidate(sampleBufferRef)
                    }
                }
            }


            if assetReader.status == AVAssetReaderStatus.Completed {
                print("ok ")


             }



        } catch var error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
            NSLog("%@", "\(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

To get back the stream, i have to write some code in the following part , but i have no idea how to perform that. Any help will be appreciated.

```
func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

    }
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Did you found any solutions?